# Terrible webcam resolution in Dell Precision 5560 and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dell, display-resolution, webcam, 22.04, cheese

I have got my new Dell Precision 5560. The webcam is `Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD`  It's specification says that the max resolution is 0.92 Megapixel, 1280 x 720 (HD) at 30 FPS. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with `5.15.0-27-generic` kernel.

However  when I run Cheese or any other recording software the default resolution I can get is 640x480. Video stream is normal, with colors but the quality is insufficient.

In tried changing the resolution in Cheese preferences. But 1280x720 turns off color and adds hundreds of vertical white stripes to the stream... Then the stream hangs.
[image]

There are 3 other 'cameras' available in Cheese preferences but they also give me stripy stream...

I would appreciate any ideas on how to change the resolution to anything decent.

Comment: does this work in any other program (skype, OBS, etc)? It appears that Cheese can't use a specific video format that your webcam might be using

Comment: No. It doesn't. I tried skype and guvcview with no luck

Comment: Experiencing the same with `Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:5271 IMC Networks Integrated RGB Camera` on a Lenovo P1. Downgrading cheese resolution gives me a picture, but i.e. `teams` goes into a hang.